# aggregation: sum columns by ID and average columns by id (gender and location unchanged)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to aggregate my data.  I want to sum all of of the columns, for a given ID, and average the other column.  Here is what I have and what I would like. Also, I need to put this into a new table.

```
ID    Cash    charge  total  proportion    gender   location

1     3.00     2.00    5.00   .66     m       28972

1     2.00     1.00    3.00   .66     m        28972

1     3.00     0.00    3.00     1      m        28972

1     4.00     2.00    6.00    .66      m        28972

2     3.00     3.00    6.00     .5      f        37352

2     4.00     6.00   10.00     .4      f        37352
```

This is what I want in a new table. I want to sum the cash, charge, and total for a given ID and I want to average the proportion for a given ID. Gender and location need to be there, but not summed or averaged

```
ID    SumCash    Sumcharge  Sumtotal  AvgProportion   Gender   Location

1     12.00    5.00   17.00   .745    m    28972

2     7.00    9.00   16.00   .45      f    37352
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? e.g. `GROUP BY ID` and `SUM` and `AVG`. Also why store in a new table? If you need this materialized at all you can use an indexed view and it will be kept in synch with the source data.

Comment: Eventually I will need to do other things with the original data, so I do not want to edit that in any way/have to recreate this current subset.  I tried Select sum(cash) From MyTable Group By ID, but that didnt work.  I had additional columns at the time but now I only have what I'm aggregating.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result by using the aggregate functions `sum()` and `avg()`:

```
select id,
  sum(cash) SumCash,
  sum(charge) sumCharge,
  sum(total) sumTotal,
  avg(proportion) avgProportion
from yt
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3479b/1)

Edit, with the new columns that you added you can still get the result by using the aggregate functions. You will just need to include the `gender` and `location` columns in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
select id,
  sum(cash) SumCash,
  sum(charge) sumCharge,
  sum(total) sumTotal,
  avg(proportion) avgProportion,
  gender,
  location
from yt
group by id, gender, location;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eaa7d/1)

Comment: ive defined proportion as decimal(18,2)

Comment: @user2448666 This above with still work even if `proportion` is a `decimal`

Answer (score 0):

Here the query what you need:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(A.CASH), SUM(A.CHARGE), SUM(A.TOTAL), SUM(A.AVGPROPORTION)/COUNT(ID)
FROM A
WHERE A.ID = ID
GROUP BY A.ID
```